# Unable to Connect to SQL Server getting firewall rule error

Tags: sql-server, azure

Its a bit strange. Until yesterday I was able to connect to all of my SQL Servers. Once I restarted my computer, a new firewall seems to have been unexpectedly added. I tried to sign in to my azure account, but I am still getting the same error.

[image]

Comment: Your SQL Server is hosted on Microsoft Azure?

Comment: The OP's image would suggest so. It would help if you tagged the relevant Azure technology you are using here, Hakuna Matata.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem myself in the past, and trying to configure firewall settings through SQL Server Management Studio could not solve it for me. Instead I did this:

1. Log into Microsoft Azure
2. Go to your SQL Server that you are having difficulties with
3. From the menu, select "Firewalls and Virtual Networks"
4. Select "Add Client IP"
5. Enter your public IP address.

[image: annotated screenshot]

There is also documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-security-tutorial)